# Why does hash table printing function not work?

Tags: c, hashtable

I don't understand why when I create the `person` structs and insert before, it outputs correctly, but the `person` structs created from the text file do not.

In my program, I would like to display the correct index and string pairs.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_NAME 256
#define TABLE_SIZE 20

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int age;
} person;

person * hash_table[TABLE_SIZE];

unsigned int hash(char *name)
{
    unsigned int hash_value = 0;
    int length = strnlen(name, MAX_NAME);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        hash_value += name[i];
        hash_value = (hash_value * name[i]) % TABLE_SIZE;
    }
    return hash_value;
}

void init_hash_table(void) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
        hash_table[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void print_table(void) {
    for (int m = 0; m < TABLE_SIZE; m++) {
        if (hash_table[m] == NULL) {
            printf("\t%i\t---\n", m);   
        } else {
            printf("\t%i\t%s\n", m, hash_table[m]->name);
        }
    }
}

bool hash_table_insert(person *p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return false;
    int index = hash(p->name);
    printf("%d\n", index);
    if (hash_table[index] != NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    hash_table[index] = p;
    printf("Inserted %s\n", p->name);
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
    char buffer[MAX_NAME];
    unsigned int hash_counts[TABLE_SIZE];
    unsigned char count;
    
    srand(time(NULL));

    init_hash_table();
    print_table();

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    
    person p1 = {.name ="JACOB", .age=10};
    person p2 = {.name ="ANDRE", .age=13};
    person p3 = {.name ="MARCUS", .age=23};

    hash_table_insert(&p1);
    hash_table_insert(&p2);
    hash_table_insert(&p3); 
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) == 1 && count < TABLE_SIZE) { 
        count++;
        hash_counts[hash(buffer)]++;
        person p1 = {.name = buffer, .age = rand() % 100};
        hash_table_insert(&p1);
    }
    
    print_table();

    /*
    for (int j = 0; j < TABLE_SIZE; j++) {
        printf("%-3d: ", j);
        for (int k = 0; k < hash_counts[j]; k++) {
            printf("x");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    */
}
```

I try to input

```
Isidoro
Mechelle
Etta
Cozmo
Torey
Gizela
Ludvig
Gaby
Bud
Skipp
Lura
Linda
Mathilda
Carlynne
Felix
Roosevelt
Norbert
Renee
Holly
Keefer
Zachariah
Felice
Collie
Arielle
Langsdon
Teodora
Tine
Floris
Annmarie
Anita
Boycey
Conway
Beverlee
Derril
Ann-marie
Cori
Hanny
...
```

I receive the following output:

```
    0   ---
    1   ---
    2   ---
    3   ---
    4   ---
    5   ---
    6   ---
    7   ---
    8   ---
    9   ---
    10  ---
    11  ---
    12  ---
    13  ---
    14  ---
    15  ---
    16  ---
    17  ---
    18  ---
    19  ---
    0   Zachariah
    1   Zachariah
    2   Zachariah
    3   ---
    4   Zachariah
    5   ANDRE
    6   ---
    7   ---
    8   Zachariah
    9   Zachariah
    10  ---
    11  Zachariah
    12  Zachariah
    13  Zachariah
    14  ---
    15  ---
    16  Zachariah
    17  Zachariah
    18  JACOB
    19  MARCUS
```

Comment: Try (1) instrumenting the code with diagnostic messages (2)  single-stepping the code in a debugger.

Comment: What do you suppose is the value of `&p1` the first time through the loop? The second? Etc.? Why? What do you think will *happen to the struct that was created the previous time* through the loop, when `person p1 = {.name = buffer, .age = rand() % 100};` runs again each time? Why? (What do you think happens to `p1` at the end of each loop? Hint: what happens to, for example, `count`, when `main` ends?)

Comment: Suppose for the sake of argument that you need to store information about the whole population of Europe. 750000000 people, give or take. You increase `TABLE_SIZE` appropriately. Great, your hash table has 750000000 pointers. Now you would also need memory for these pointers to point to: 750000000 `person` records, and each has a pointer to a name, so you also need memory for 750000000 names. Can you explain to your nearest rubber duck where all that memory should come from?

Comment: You don't have any code to handle hash collisions; you will need code to do that.

Comment: A couple of really good links for learning/understanding hashtables [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hashtables - eternally confuzzled](https://web.archive.org/web/20171201141916/http://eternallyconfuzzled.com:80/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) (wayback archive of page).

Comment: Welcome to UB... This code "remembers" many copies of the address of an _automatic_ block of memory that goes out of scope at the end of the loop... Lucky you that it didn't SEG_FAULT when trying to print...

Answer (score 1):

You're pointing to the same pointer `p1` each loop, you need to dynamically allocate it to hold different values.

The following code should work

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) == 1 && count < TABLE_SIZE) { 
    count++;
    hash_counts[hash(buffer)]++;
    person *p1 = malloc(sizeof(person));
    p1->name = malloc(strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char) + 1);
    strcpy(p1->name, buffer);
    p1->age = rand() % 100;
    hash_table_insert(p1);
}
```

Comment: `p1->name = malloc(strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char));` is not long enough to hold the null terminator, too... Replace the `malloc()` and `strcpy()` with `strdup()` that does both operations correctly... THEN, verify that `strdup()` hasn't returned a NULL (allocation failed)...

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that there is a problem with inserting names of people read from a text file, which could be for a few reasons.

1. **Memory management problem**:
   In your code, you use a fixed buffer to read the names of people in the file. However, when you create a person structure for these names and insert them into the hash table, you point directly to this buffer. This means that every time you read a new name from the file, it overwrites the old name in the buffer. Therefore, all entries in the hash table will end up pointing to the same name (that is, the last name in the file).

   To solve this problem, every time you read a name from the file, you need to allocate new memory space for this name, and copy the name into this new space. This way, each hash table entry will have its own independent name.
2. **File content problem**:
   Make sure your file content is expected and well-formed. For example, there should be only one name per line.

To fix memory management issues, you can use the `strdup` function to copy strings. Here's an example of how to copy a string from buffer and assign a value to the person structure:

```c
while (fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) == 1 && count < TABLE_SIZE) {
     person *p = malloc(sizeof(person));
     p->name = strdup(buffer); // copy string to new memory space
     p->age = rand() % 100;
     hash_table_insert(p);
     count++;
}
```

Finally, remember to free the memory you allocated with `malloc` and `strdup` at the end of the program to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in main inserts a pointer to `p1` each time. That makes all the hash entries be the same (and hold a dangling pointer).

You should instead allocate a new struct for each entry.